# Replace multiple newlines with single newlines during reading file

Tags: python, regex, file

I have the next code which reads from multiple files, parses obtained lines and prints the result:

```
import os
import re

files=[]
pars=[]

for i in os.listdir('path_to_dir_with_files'):
    files.append(i)

for f in files:
    with open('path_to_dir_with_files'+str(f), 'r') as a:
       pars.append(re.sub('someword=|\,.*|\#.*','',a.read()))

for k in pars:
   print k
```

But I have problem with multiple new lines in output:

```
test1


test2
```

Instead of it I want to obtain the next result without empty lines in output:

```
 test1
 test2
```

and so on.

I tried playing with regexp:

```
pars.append(re.sub('someword=|\,.*|\#.*|^\n$','',a.read()))
```

But it doesn't work. Also I tried using strip() and rstrip() including replace. It also doesn't work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use a second regex to replace multiple new lines with a single new line and use strip to get rid of the last new line.

```
import os
import re

files=[]
pars=[]

for i in os.listdir('path_to_dir_with_files'):
    files.append(i)

for f in files:
    with open('path_to_dir_with_files/'+str(f), 'r') as a:
        word = re.sub(r'someword=|\,.*|\#.*','', a.read())
        word = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', word).strip()
        pars.append(word)

for k in pars:
   print k
```

Comment: Could you do this line-wise, not file-wise? Like for line in f: And can you explain what the re.sub does? Comma and hash are escaped, I do not understand the someword=. There is no = in the example..

Comment: Sure you can do it line-wise but `f` is the filename in this case not the content. `re.sub` replaces stuff that matches the first argument with whatever you put in the second argument. Check the docs and try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Without changing your code much, one easy way would just be to check if the line is empty before you print it, e.g.:

```
import os
import re

files=[]
pars=[]

for i in os.listdir('path_to_dir_with_files'):
    files.append(i)

for f in files:
    with open('path_to_dir_with_files'+str(f), 'r') as a:
        pars.append(re.sub('someword=|\,.*|\#.*','',a.read()))

for k in pars:
    if not k.strip() == "":
        print k
```

*** EDIT
Since each element in pars is actually the entire content of the file (not just a line), you need to go through an replace any double end lines, easiest to do with re

```
import os
import re

files=[]
pars=[]

for i in os.listdir('path_to_dir_with_files'):
    files.append(i)

for f in files:
    with open('path_to_dir_with_files'+str(f), 'r') as a:
        pars.append(re.sub('someword=|\,.*|\#.*','',a.read()))

for k in pars:
    k = re.sub(r"\n+", "\n", k)
    if not k.strip() == "":
        print k
```

Note that this doesn't take care of the case where a file ends with a newline and the next one begins with one - if that's a case you are worried about you need to either add extra logic to deal with it or change the way you're reading the data in

Comment: or just `if k.strip()`

Comment: This should also be done while adding to `pars` and not when iterating over `pars`.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't give an appropriate result. In case of if not k.strip() == "" I still obtain multiple empty lines. If displaying just list without iterating through it I obtain: test1[*]\n\n\n test2\n test5\ntest7[*]\ntest[*]\n etc...

Comment: Oh I see, because you are just reading the entire line into each item in pars, so it isn't printing line by line. I edited my answer, it just uses regular expressions to go through and get rid of any duplicate \n with a single \n

Answer (score 2):

just a simple one, but may not be efficent.

```py
entire_file = "whatever\nmay\n\n\n\nhappen"

while '\n\n' in entire_file:
    entire_file = entire_file.replace("\n\n", "\n")

print(entire_file)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This has a bug. It only cuts the \n in half. It replaces every double set, \n\n, with one \n. So if there are 4, \n\n\n\n, there will now be 2, \n\n.

Answer (score 0):

Use lookahead regular expression to find all of the double return characters `r'\n(?=\n)` and replace that with nothing. This will find and replace all of these cases in one pass

```
import re

files=[]
pars=[]

for i in os.listdir('path_to_dir_with_files'):
    files.append(i)

for f in files:
    with open('path_to_dir_with_files'+str(f), 'r') as a:
       pars.append(re.sub(r'\n(?=\n)','',a.read()))

for k in pars:
   print k
```

Note: this won't help you if the last character is \n of files[0] and the first character of file[1] is also '\n' but... you can use strip for this and your print will take care of the single space between files

```
import os
import re

files=[]
pars=[]

for i in os.listdir('path_to_dir_with_files'):
    files.append(i)

for f in files:
    with open('path_to_dir_with_files'+str(f), 'r') as a:
       pars.append(re.sub(r'\n(?=\n)','',a.read().strip()))

for k in pars:
   print k
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```
re.sub(r'[\r\n][\r\n]{2,}', '\n\n', sourceFileContents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex is the only solution here (apart from using a loop to iterate over the string)

`text = re.sub(r'[\n]+', '\n', text)`

Answer (score -3):

Just would like to point out: regexes aren't the best way to handle that.  Replacing two empty lines by one in a Python str is quite simple, no need for re:

```
entire_file = "whatever\nmay\n\nhappen"
entire_file = entire_file.replace("\n\n", "\n")
```

And voila!  Much faster than re and (in my opinion) much easier to read.

Comment: This won't work if the file contains more than 2 consecutive "\n" like "whatever\nmay\n\n\nhappen"

Comment: It's true, but still could do with a loop: `while "\n\n" in text: text = text.replace("\n\n", "\n")`

Comment: This form of 'elision' is fragile and requires adaption based on the length of the desired run.  E.g. desiring two newlines between "paragraphs" would require **three** `.replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n")` calls.  Iterative reconstruction means a duplication of the entire string per iteration.  Regular expressions can far more easily combine _actual measured runs of repeating characters_, with explicit control over run length: `\n{min,max}`, and perform such an operation in, essentially, O(1) time without excessive memory duplication.