# remove all the EOFs (extra empty lines) at the end of jsonl files

Tags: python, json, regex, file-writing, jsonlines

I am working with jsonl files that look something like this in VSCode editor:

first.jsonl

```
1.{"ConnectionTime": 730669.644775033,"objectId": "eHFvTUNqTR","CustomName": "Relay Controller","FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96","DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561","PeripheralType": 9,"updatedAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z","Model": "DF Bluno","HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7","Serial": "0123456789","createdAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z","Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
2.{"ConnectionTime": 702937.7616419792, "objectId": "uYuT3zgyez", "CustomName": "Relay Controller", "FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96", "DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561", "PeripheralType": 9, "updatedAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", "Model": "DF Bluno", "HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7", "Serial": "0123456789", "createdAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", "Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
3.
4.
5.
6.
```

second.jsonl

```
1.{"ConnectionTime": 730669.644775033,"objectId": "eHFvTUNqTR","CustomName": "Relay Controller","FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96","DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561","PeripheralType": 9,"updatedAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z","Model": "DF Bluno","HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7","Serial": "0123456789","createdAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z","Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
2.{"ConnectionTime": 702937.7616419792, "objectId": "uYuT3zgyez", "CustomName": "Relay Controller", "FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96", "DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561", "PeripheralType": 9, "updatedAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", "Model": "DF Bluno", "HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7", "Serial": "0123456789", "createdAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", "Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
3.
4.
```

then many more, that have random number of end lines/ EOF markers. I wanted to have either single or empty lines at end of each file. I was keep getting this error `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from Nonejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)` 
using this method:

```py
filenames = glob.glob("folder_with_all_jsonl/*.jsonl")

#read file by file, write file by file. Simple.

for f in filenames:
#path to the jsonl file/s 
    data_json = io.open(f, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') # Opens in the JSONL file
    data_python = extract_json(data_json)
#.....code omitted
    for line in data_python: # it would fail here because of an empty line
        print(line.get(objectId))
        #and so on
```

I removed some extra lines manually and I was able to process through my 2 jsonl files.

I have looked at these SO boards:
1>[Removing a new line feed in json file using Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794782/removing-a-new-line-feed-in-json-file-using-python)

2>[Replace multiple newlines with single newlines during reading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629561/replace-multiple-newlines-with-single-newlines-during-reading-file)

Please provide me hint/help. I will appreciate it!!

I wanted to have each file in this format:
first.jsonl

```
1.{"ConnectionTime": 730669.644775033,"objectId": "eHFvTUNqTR","CustomName": "Relay Controller","FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96","DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561","PeripheralType": 9,"updatedAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z","Model": "DF Bluno","HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7","Serial": "0123456789","createdAt": "2016-12-13T15:50:41.626Z","Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
2.{"ConnectionTime": 702937.7616419792, "objectId": "uYuT3zgyez", "CustomName": "Relay Controller", "FirmwareRevision": "FW V1.96", "DeviceID": "F1E4746E-DCEC-495B-AC75-1DFD66527561", "PeripheralType": 9, "updatedAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", "Model": "DF Bluno", "HardwareRevision": "HW V1.7", "Serial": "0123456789", "createdAt": "2016-12-13T08:08:29.829Z", "Manufacturer": "DFRobot"}
```

**EDIT:**
I have used Zhengyang Song answer and chepner advice
I actually have two 4gb files, doing this:

```py
results = []
for f in glob.glob("folder_with_all_jsonl/*.jsonl"):
    with open(f, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            try:
                results.append(json.loads(line)) # read each line of the file
            except ValueError:
                print(f)
    with open(f,'w', encoding= 'utf-8-sig') as outfile:
        for result in results:
            outfile.write(json.dumps(result) + "\n")
```

leads to error `line 852, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread` I am on my personal windows machine.

**EDIT 2:** I migrated to my work machine, and I was able to solve this. Any input how can we prevent this on personal machines?? Like parallel processing??

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: hello Sushanth brother, I have edited the question. Please look at the bottom of it. Thank you!!

Comment: FYI, there's no reason to call `readlines`; you can iterate over the file directly with `for line in infile`, rather than reading the entire file into a list before iteration begins.

Comment: Thank you, I am bit new to python so don't have lot of concepts. Learning as I go, so I will definitely remember your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to respond to your last code snippet.

You can change the line

```
json.dump(result, outfile, indent=None)
```

to something like:

```
for one_item in result:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(one_item)+"\n")
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to change from `f.` to `outfile.` Let me check with my file really quick :)

Comment: Hello, I am keep getting this error, which I don't think coming from your answer. It's a 4gb file. `line 852, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread`

Comment: Yes, that error message seems from other code, and has nothing to do with this.

Comment: This actually works. I had to migrate my work to my work desktop. That desktop is more powerful. Thank you Song for your help :)